# HttpRequest callout timeout

Tags: apex, httprequest

Is there a way to check the `setTimeout()` value of a HttpRequest object?

use case: a method is receiving a HttpRequest object. I want to check if `setTimeout` is setup in the object before setting it up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> **The default timeout is 10 seconds**. A custom timeout can be defined for each callout. The minimum is 1 millisecond and the maximum is 120,000 milliseconds. See the examples in the next section for how to set custom timeouts for Web services or HTTP callouts.

The default timeout is 10 seconds unless you set it via `setTimeout(timeout)`.

There is no method on `HttpRequest` object to check the timeout value.

Resources:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm